# Graph - strongly connected components

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, version-control

Is there any fast way to determine the size of the largest strongly connected component in a graph?

I mean, like, the obvious approach would mean determining every SCC (could be done using two `DFS` calls, I suppose) and then looping through them and taking the maximum.

I'm pretty sure there has to be some better approach if I only need to have the size of that component and only the largest one, but I can't think of a good solution. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but why would you want to do this since algorithms like Tarjan is linear and has a very small constant overhead to determine all the SCCs. It is also easy to implement as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer your question with another question -
How can you determine which value in a set is the largest without examining all of the values?

Comment: Well, sometimes it's possible, e.g. if you have additional information about your set / smth like that. I don't know, maybe determining - maximizing approach would be the only and the best at the same time, but my intuition says that there must be a better way. If you're absolutely sure this can't be done faster, I would trust you :)

Comment: I am not sure, this is intuition. There are algorithms to get the components in one DFS if I recall. I am highly doubtful you will find an algorithm that does it in less than a single scan. If you do have some information about the graph, post it, and maybe we can come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you could use [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) which needs only one DFS instead of two. If you understand the algorithm clearly, the SCCs form a DAG and this algo finds them in the reverse topological sort order. So if you have a sense of the graph (like a visual representation) and if you know that relative big SCCs occur at end of the DAG then you could stop the algorithm once first few SCCs are found.